# Restrictions accessing the url from c#

Tags: c#, .net

Can there be any restrictions on the IIS service, web.config or somewhere that could stop accessing an url from a c# code?

My function that seems to have problems with accessing url is pdfConverter.GetPdfBytesFromUrl(url).

If I access the same url from the browser it works fine but when accessing it with the above function it gives a message: Could not render the url. Could not get image from url.The URL is not accessible..

I'm not sure what could it be.

Comment: looks like that's the problem of your `pdfConverter`, why not share with everyone here a little info about it?

Comment: Well, obviously there can be restrictions. Are you sure what is returned to the pdf converter is actually a pdf? Could it be that in your browser you have logged on to the website and that the url, when not logged in, serves the login page instead? (or similar)

Comment: It turned out that the function pdfConverter.GetPdfBytesFromUrl(url) works fine with any url other than the url of the website it is on. So the webiste is example.com and the script accesses a specific url, gets html fro it and converts to pdf pdfConverter.GetPdfBytesFromUrl('http://example.com/html2pdf.html'). that doesn't work but if you put something else instead of http://example.com/html2pdf.html it works fine. There are no restrictions in terms of authentication or anything like that that would stop accessing this url (as far as I'm aware but I don't really know where to look).